# MySQL: Concatenate two information, return a virtual column and in sequence perform an INNER JOIN with the column

Tags: mysql, join, sum, concatenation

In my project, I need make a Column with Concat information, like this:
CONCAT('SIP/', name) AS sipAgent.

And this works, but when i try to make a INNER JOIN with the column sipAgent, has error :(

And after inner join i need to SUM the results for each result of

like that:

```
----------------------------------
| NAME | sipAgent | notAnswered  |
----------------------------------
| aaa  | SIP/aaa  |    132       |
| bbb  | SIP/bbb  |    50        |
----------------------------------
```

Name is the reference of agent, sipAgent is 'SIP/' + name, and noAnswered is the number of rows returned in a inner join.

Here is my 'test-query':

```
SELECT *, CONCAT('SIP/', tab_sippeers.name) AS sipAgent, SUM(queue_log.event) as notAnswered
FROM 'ipbx.tab_sippeers'

join 'queue_log' on tab_sippeers.sipAgent = queue_log.agent
```

But, is returning error...
Sorry for bad english, and thanks alot for help!

Comment: edit your question with error also.

Comment: It is noteworthy that we cannot refer to evaluated expression aliases in the `ON` clause of `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query doesn't look right in other ways but you could concat in the join

```
   SELECT *, CONCAT('SIP/', tab_sippeers.name) AS sipAgent, SUM(queue_log.event) as notAnswered
FROM `ipbx.tab_sippeers`
join `queue_log` on CONCAT('SIP/', tab_sippeers.name)  = queue_log.agent;
```

and table names and column names should be enclose in backticks not single quotes if you want to enclose them at all.
[When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: You can add this to answer: It is noteworthy that we cannot refer to evaluated expression aliases in the ON clause of JOIN.

Comment: The query worked in parts ... it is now bringing the column 'notAnswered', but return is always 0.

And it is always bringing 1 line of return, I would need to return all registered agents this information.

I forgot to point out also that the notAnswered is the result count of:
sipAgent where the results are queue_log.event = RINGNOANSWER

Comment: It would help if you added sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html